# Is it possible to indent a string in Matlab?

Tags: string, matlab, syntax

I am outputting my data as follows (this works fine):

```
fprintf(fid,'%6.2f Time (sec) \n %6.2f Conc \n %6.2f pK \n %6.2f B1',aaa);
```

However, if I use (for readability)

```
fprintf(fid,'
  %6.2f Time (sec) \n
  %6.2f Conc \n
  %6.2f pK \n
  %6.2f B1',
aaa);
```

Matlab throws a syntax error.

Is it possible to indent a string the way I am showing above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
fprintf(fid,[...
  '%6.2f Time (sec) \n', ...
  '%6.2f Conc \n', ...
  '%6.2f pK \n', ...
  '%6.2f B1'], ...
aaa);
```

where the string gets broken into components inside a `[ ... ]` block spread with [continuation lines](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bsw6ppl-1.html).

Comment: thx - I am getting a warning using this - "The expression on this line will generate an error when executed.  The error will be: Error using ==> vertcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent." This warning also shows when removing the commas as @dominique suggested above - any ideas?

Comment: I have to admit I didn't try it.  Maybe make it two statements, one to assign to a formatstr (with indents) and then use 'fprintf(fid, formatstr, aaa)' ?

Comment: Actually, I *did* just try at the command-line where it worked fine, including use of 'backslash-n'.

Comment: thx @dirk - actually it worked without the commas -- I had a few returns between lines that were causing the error

Comment: Ah, yes, those are optional inside `[ ... ]`.

Answer (score 1):

does not really help readability but it's valid syntax:

```
    fprintf(fid, [ ...
'  %6.2f Time (sec) \n' ...
'  %6.2f Conc \n' ...
'  %6.2f pK \n' ...
'  %6.2f B1' ], ...
    aaa ...
    );
```